# Hibernate query for joining two tables

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have two tables Employee and User. I need to join these tables like,

"select userName,firstName from Employee left join User on Employee.userId = User.userId"

How can I do it in Hibernate-spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from your description the way you are accessing the the data, meaning using criteria query, HQL or using the mappings. But in general for forcing join in resultant SQL query, you  need to mention explicit configuration in mappings and criteria queries. Checkout [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-unidirectional-join) for joining tables. This refers to Hibernate 3.x not sure what version you are using. [This](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies) link gives concise version of fetching strategies.

Comment: I need to access data like,  List list= hibernateTemplate.find("FROM Employee e left join User u where u.userId = e.userId);   as I am new to hibernate I am not sure whether it will works or not.

Comment: Check out [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins) link which details about the associations and join queries.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot express arbitrary joins on any two columns in JPQL, effectively there is no 'on.'  You need to express the relationship between the two entities as an object relationship (map one on the other) then you just write `Employees e left join Users u`.

I think that's as much as can be said without seeing your entities.